# C# And XAML Line Series

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm seriously stuck now.

I have code that reads from the database the amount of calls per hour, however when it come time to mapping them to the graph, nothing shows...

How do i map it using the following command: `ls.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, counter).Select(k => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(callHour[k], callCounter[k])).ToArray();`

Here is all my code:

XAML:

```
    <DVC:Chart Name="Chart"
               Background="#463F3F">                
        <DVC:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>
        </DVC:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllAgentHourData();
    }

    private void AllAgentHourData()
    {
        string[] qId = new string[100];
        int[] callHour = new int[100];
        int[] callCounter = new int[100];
        int qCounter = 0;
        //int counter = 0;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=nl-reportserver;Database=RC_Dailer_WH;User Id=sa;Password=<password>");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        //cmd.CommandText = "Select distinct queueid from RC_call_logs order by queueid";
        cmd.CommandText = "Select CONVERT(date, starttime, 120) AS callDate, queueid, datepart(hour,convert(datetime,starttime,111)) AS cHour, count(id) as numberOfCalls from RC_call_logs where convert(date,starttime,120) = convert(date,getdate(),120) and queueid = 17000 group by CONVERT(date, starttime, 120), datepart(hour,convert(datetime,starttime,111)), queueid order by callDate, queueid, cHour";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;



        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                callHour[qCounter] = reader.GetInt32(2);
                callCounter[qCounter] = reader.GetInt32(3);
                qCounter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Error message");
        }
        reader.Close();
        sqlConnection1.Close();

        LineSeries ls = new LineSeries();

        ls.Title = "17000";
        ls.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
        ls.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");

        ls.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, qCounter).Select(i=> new KeyValuePair<int, int>(callHour[i], callCounter[i])).ToArray();

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add line series to chart

```
Chart.Series.Add(ls);
```

Comment: Im about to shoot myself haha, i had that when i started and i deleted it by mistake :( Thank you so much